# No static Main method and bin/debug .exe not found

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2013

Im programming in C# with my Visual Studio 2013 Community I'm farely new at using this IDE, C# and programming in Objects.

So I have a solution that have 2 proyects, one is called "Console" and the other is called "Entities".

Console have the program.cs and there it sits my main entry point (Static void main). There I'm instantiating a class called "Product" that it is inside Entities.

When I build my program the IDE is informing me about two problems:

Error   1   Program 'c:\<>\<>\<>\C Sharp\Tareas y Practicas\Consola\Entidades\obj\Debug\Entidades.exe' **does not contain a static 'Main' method suitable for an entry point**

The other error is this:
Error   2   Metadata file 'C:\<>\<>\<>\C Sharp\Tareas y Practicas\Consola\Entidades\bin\Debug\Entidades.exe' **could not be found**

If I go to 'Console' > Properties > Build the output path is bin\Debug\

In the Debug tab I see 'Start Action' > 'Start Project' and 'Enable debuggers' > 'Enable the Visual Studio hosting process'

Same goes with the 'Entities' proyect.

I created a reference from Entities to Console and use this namespace on Console.

Does anyone knows why I can't run the program?

Comment: nevermind I saw the error.

For future reference you have to go where your class libraries are in my case is Entities, right click, go to properties and in Application tab go to Output type and change it to class library.

Comment: You mixed up the library and the application?

Answer (score 0):

nevermind I saw the error. For future reference you have to go where your class libraries are in my case is Entities, right click, go to properties and in Application tab go to Output type and change it to class library. –